# how do you find app bar height in react material ui app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to create an image that spans the whole screen when first opening my website. I am using react and material ui. Currently my JSX looks like roughly like this. I have used the default material ui theme.

```
<AppBar>
//code in between 
</AppBar>

<Container sx={{margin: '0px', padding: '0px'}}>
   <img src={headerPicture} style={{minHeight: '100vh', maxWidth: '100vw'}}/>
</Container>
```

The issue is, 100vh does not take into account the height of the app bar, therefore the image + the app bar is larger than the screen. I would imagine I would have to do something like this:

```
<img src={headerPicture} style={{minHeight: '100vh - AppBarHeight', maxWidth: '100vw'}}/>
```

where the AppBarWidth equals the height of the app bar as it changes responsively.

Do you know how I would go about finding out the height of the app bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this in one app by setting fixed height on AppBar (can be responsive) and applying that using constants.

- AppBar.js (example)

```
export const APP_BAR_HEIGHT = 80;
export const APP_BAR_HEIGHT_LG = 140;

const AppBar = () => {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: isLargeScreen ? APP_BAR_HEIGHT_LG : APP_BAR_HEIGHT}}>
            {/* app bar here */}
        </div>
    );
}
export default AppBar;
```

Then you import and use those constants in your project.

**Additionally**

Write a hook

```
const useWindowHeight = () => {

    const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(window.innerHeight);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        }
    }, []);
    return height;
}
```

Use this value instead of vh, because the window height changes in some mobile device while scrolling. In the end, this could look like this:

```
import AppBar, { APP_BAR_HEIGHT, APP_BAR_HEIGHT_LG } from 'whateverpath';

// ...
const windowHeight = useWindowHeight();
return (
    <>
        <AppBar>
             //code in between 
        </AppBar>

        <Container sx={{margin: '0px', padding: '0px'}}>
            <img src={headerPicture} style={{minHeight: windowHeight - APP_BAR_HEIGHT, maxWidth: '100vw'}}/>
        </Container>
    </>
)
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful!! Just one question, how do you get the isLargeScreen variable?

Comment: See [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive)

Comment: I think it was supposed to be 'window.addEventListener'  instead of 'document' as then the height changes based on the window size?

Comment: You maybe correct. I did not test this, but for me both ways would work. I'm accepting your suggestion